# What’s this game of a woman throwing a person up into the air?

Tags: game-identification

I found this game on TikTok and I’d love to know what it’s called. Sadly the person who uploaded the video doesn’t respond. Can you help me please?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks to be called [*Lady Toss*](https://m.apkpure.com/lady-toss/com.bigdog.games.ladytoss).  It reminds me of "Kitten Cannon" from back in the day, where the goal is to shoot/throw something as far as possible.

Here is also a video:

Comment: Thanks for including the links, Googling that might give some weird results...